# TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple. problem with widgets

Tags: python, url, tkinter, typeerror, tk-toolkit

Im trying to get information off a website into a widget, it works but i want to have each piece of text it 'finds' to be displayed on a new line. I've tried + '/n' and + '''
''') but i get the same error.

```py
def Supplies_scraper():
    if instorechoices1.counter !=1:
        url='(url)'
        web_page=urlopen(url)
        html_code=web_page.read().decode("UTF-8")
        web_page.close()
        products = (findall('''data-desc =(.*?)data-price =''',html_code))[:5],


        shopping_list.delete(0.0, END)
        shopping_cart.delete(0.0, END)



        if products:
            shopping_list.insert(0.0, products + '/n')


            shopping_list.insert(0.0, '''Source: (URL)
''')
            shopping_list.insert(0.0,'''--------{ Best Health Supplies }-------
''')

    elif instorechoices1.counter ==1:
        shopping_list.delete(0.0, END)
        shopping_list.insert(END, 'Due to shortages there is only 1 of each item category per order'+ '\n')

    if instorechoices1.counter != 2:
        instorechoices1.counter +=1
```

Comment: Show the exact error with trace. I can't see where here that error would be caused by.

Comment: Also note, adding and removing at the front of a list is quite expensive. Ideally, you should either work with the end of the list, or switch to a different structure like a dequeue.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that you have trailing , in this line

```
products = (findall('''data-desc =(.*?)data-price =''',html_code))[:5],
```

which mean that after it `products` is `tuple`, attempt of concatenating tuple with str or str with tuple will result in

```
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple
```

Is that trailing `,` intentional in your code? If not remove it and please check what type it is, for example by doing:

```
products = (findall('''data-desc =(.*?)data-price =''',html_code))[:5]
print(type(products))
```

If it is `str` then you might concatenate it with `\n`, if it is `tuple` or `list` you need convert it for str first, if all elements of `list` or `tuple` are `str`s you might use `.join` following way:

```
my_tuple = ('1','2','3')
my_list = ['1','2','3']
joined_tuple = ','.join(my_tuple)
joined_list = ','.join(my_list)
print(joined_tuple)  # 1,2,3
print(joined_list)  # 1,2,3
```

Comment: Thankyou, the type is now string but it will just print 1,2,3 rather than what it has searched for.